# In UI Local notifications maximum number of characters allowed

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Maximum number of characters allowed in `alertBody` of `UILocalNotification`?

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 10, use UNNotificationRequest instead, UILocalNotification is deprecated. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification

Comment: There is no such limit but I have seen it only shows 256 character (aplhanumeric, special including).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit limit for the `alertBody`. If the text is longer than the available space it will be truncated accordingly by the system. Also, please bear in mind that `UILocalNotification` is deprecated in iOS 10 (you will have to use `UserNotifications` framework).